# Source Insight cannot recognize function definitions

Tags: source-insight

If any macro shows up in the definition, source insight would fail to recognize the function correctly.

Like this:

header:

```
//whateverheader.h
#define DECLINLINE(type) static __inline__ type
```

source:

```
//whateversource.c
static DECLINLINE(int) FuncAnyFunction(int arg) { ... }
```

Source Insight CANNOT recognize the function "FuncAnyFunction", and instead, it marks "DECLINLINE" as a function, hence in the symbol tab of source insight, I see millions of functions with the same name "DECLINLINE" instead of their real names.

Moreover, I cannot jump to the definition of the function from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your macro definition to a Token Macro file. For [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it is `C.tom` in `My Documents\Source Insight\` or project data directory. Just add the next line:

```
DECLINLINE(X)
```

More details can be found at [source-insight](/questions/tagged/source-insight) documentation: http://www.sourceinsight.com/docs35/af914786.htm